# Upwards of 4k event handlers on a page - too much memory?

Tags: javascript, performance

Javascript

I have a question.

I have a page that is intensive. Alot of things going on, alot of user interaction etc..

I am noticing when I am running some analytics is that I have sometimes upwards of 4-6K event handlers. To me that seems awefully excessive. I am not using any event delegation (binding the parent elem and capturing the bubble etc..). All events seem to be tied to each individual elem.

I believe I can optimize things by using event delegation but for first impression, how intensive are so many binds on a browsers memory usage? Could it bog down a page or ?

Another concerns is a TON of legacy object.create() via library prototypejs. Those are rather intensive, and slow.

My memory on the page (using google developer tools) are as follows:
initial load: 26mbs
drops to: 13mbs
user interaction on page: climbs back to ~25mbs
no interaction just page sitting: 20mbs

So, just to be clear (after giving some background info).

How many event handlers and objects created on the page will lend itself to a very slow experience for the user?

Comment: Take some old laptop, run it and see.